# django sign item with some extra values

Tags: python, django, authentication, digital-signature

i recently posted a question on here and now need another answer on this based on an alteration that needs to be done based on extra params.

previously I had the following that gave me a correct signature.

```
signature = hashlib.sha1("i=myusername&v=%s&t=7087db23de5ef07b5723" % timestamp)
```

Now I need to add the following into that string exactly as follow where **%3D** represents **=**

the problem, just adding in the string below, django is looking for another value.

```
&p=myvar%3Dmyvalue
```

I have tried a few version and seem to be getting the wrong value everytime.
signature are not my strength, thanks for the help.

```
signature = hashlib.sha1(u'i=myusername&p=myvar%s%s&v=%s&t=7087db23de5ef07b5723' % ('%3D', myvalue, timestamp))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `%%` in format string to get `%` symbol

```
'&p=myvar%%3D%s' % 'value'
```

I hope I understand you.

Also you can use [`urllib.urlencode`](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlencode)

```
>>>urllib.urlencode({'i':'fundedbyme', 'p':'myvar=%s' % myvalue})
'i=fundedbyme&p=myvar%3Dmyvalue'
```